# Python Webscraping: How can I get the string in the value attribute from the input tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all the string within the value attribute.
Like shown in the pic, I want to the string 'Denise B Martin' with this tag. (I am webscraping data from a [Fake user generator](https://www.fakepersongenerator.com/fake-name-generator))

```html
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="Denise B Martin"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the full code you have already tried (not as and image). Including the URL to the page.

Comment: Okay, what do you mean by page?  the page that I am scraping?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Do you only want the tag with `Denise B Martin`? or all of them?

Comment: all of them! I will update my post thanks!

Comment: Be wary though with posting data that (possibly) contains personal data

Comment: @Aron thanks for the reminder. These are generated from the fake user generator. I will clarify in my post as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
input_tags = content.find_all('input', class_ = 'form-control')
```

And then loop through the list to get each value:

```
for tag in input_tags:
    tag_value =  tag.get('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the content and use the `get_text()` method.

```
for item in soup.find_all("input", attrs={"class":"form-control"}):
    print(item.get_text())
```